# Excel: trying to return details from one sheet after a given time stated in another

Tags: excel, time, formulas

my problem as follows: I have sheet 1 and sheet 2. In sheet 2 i paste a report which details when certain production runs were running so we have a column featuring the product name and then another column showing each minute, by minute. If the product was being created during that time, it will be named in the adjacent column.
On Sheet 1, it shows the product names and the production run start times. It extracts the start times from sheet two like this: =INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(I12,Sheet2!$A:$A,0))
This code returns the first time occurring as the product name appears, indicating production of it has started.

Problem: this works fine until a secondary run occurs. The code simply returns the first instance and not the second, so I would want it to say "look for the first instance of this run but only start searching for it after the time mentioned in the previous cell". i.e. take the end time of the previous production and start searching after that". It should be noted that there might be gaps ebtween each production run, so we can not presume that the next run starts immediately after the first.

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need an array formula for that, for example,

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(1,(Sheet2!$A:$A=$I12)*(Sheet2!$B:$B>$J11),0))
```

An array formula must be confirmed by pressing Ctl+Shift+Enter simultaneously (instead of the customary singular Enter you press to confirm conventional formulas).

In this example, the product name is in I12 and the last production end time in J11. If J11 is blank the formula would evaluate it as zero and return the first production start time, same as your current formula.

Comment: Sorry to add to this issue but I have a similar problem whereby I want to count instances for an item occurring after a time stated in another column, any idea?